# Домашний роутер ломает общие папки Windows и ping

Tags: lan, dhcp

RT-GM-3 ломает общие папки Windows и ping. В DHCP во всех роутерах IP адреса зарезервированы  одинакого. Многий другой софт успешно переживает замену роутера, работает RDP. Но с новым роутером RT-GM-3 помирают общие папки и в стандартном разделе сеть пропадают все компы. Никто не доступен по //его_айпи/ престают пинговаться компы, но работает RDP до них. С другими роутерами разных моделей всё хорошо. Я там уже всю безопасность отключил что нашёл.  Причём с RT-GM-1 такой проблемы не было. Куда копать: Маршруты, безопасноть, DHCP, бриджы? Каким софтом может?